# Structures in C++ with arrays

Tags: c++, initialization

I do not solve the problem of displaying the following: `student[1].allgrade[1].quiz`

The portion of the code is given below.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct grade 
{ int quiz, midterm,final;
};

struct StudentRecord
{
       int studentID;
       double studentMark;
       char letter;
       struct grade allgrade[2];
} student[]={
      {10,85.2,'A',{70,80,90}},{11,66,'C',{40,50,60}}       
};

int main(void)
{
   cout<<student[1].allgrade[1].quiz<<"\n";
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hello! Can you explain what is your problem ? Do you have an error message ? What do you expect from this code ?

Answer (score 2):

According to the rule of [aggregate initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization), given the initializer `{10,85.2,'A',{70,80,90}}`, `{70,80,90}` is used to initialize the 1st element of the member array `allgrade`, then the 2nd element is **aggregate-initialized by empty list**, and its members `quiz`, `midterm`, and `final` are **value-initialized** at last. `student[1].allgrade[1].quiz` is trying to access `quiz` of the 2nd element of `allgrade`, then you'll get `0` (as the result of value-initialization).

(emphasis mine)

> If the number of initializer clauses is less than the number of members `and bases (since C++17)` or initializer list is completely empty, the remaining members `and bases (since C++17)` are initialized `by their default initializers, if provided in the class definition, and otherwise (since C++14)` by empty lists, in accordance with the usual list-initialization rules (**which performs value-initialization for non-class types and non-aggregate classes with default constructors, and aggregate initialization for aggregates**). If a member of a reference type is one of these remaining members, the program is ill-formed.

On the other hand, `student[1].allgrade[0].quiz` will give you the result `40`.

Or you can initialize the 2nd element explicitly, e.g.

```
{10,85.2,'A',{70,80,90}},{11,66,'C',{{40,50,60},{10,20,30}}}
//                                              ^^^^^^^^^^   initializer list for student[1].allgrade[1]
```

Then `student[1].allgrade[1].quiz` will give you the result `10`.

Answer (score 0):

Let's dissect that initializer list.

This is initializing `student`:

```
{10,85.2,'A',{70,80,90}},{11,66,'C',{40,50,60}}
```

This is initializing `student[1]`:

```
{11,66,'C',{40,50,60}
```

This is initializing `student[1].allgrade`:

```
{40,50,60}
```

That's just one grade... but `allgrade` is an array of TWO grades. It should instead be something like:

```
{{10, 20, 30}, {40,50,60}}
```

Put that all back together:

```
student[] = {
        {10,85.2,'A',{70,80,90}},{11,66,'C',{{10,20,30},{40,50,60}}}

};
```

And the output is `40` as you'd expect.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to set a number of dimensions to your StudentRecord struct, you just call to the variables defined *inside* it.

This means that inside your variable student of type StudentRecord, the variable `allgrade` does not need to be a vector. The vector is in fact `StudentRecord[] student`. Note that in the code below your code to the second student's quiz will be `student[1].allgrade.quiz`. That is, you call *directly* to the variable you want, for student two, inside the `grade` struct.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct grade 
{ int quiz, midterm,final;
};

struct StudentRecord
{
       int studentID;
       double studentMark;
       char letter;
       struct grade allgrade;
};

int main(void)
{
    grade first_student = { 70, 80, 90};
    grade second_student = { 40, 50, 60};
    StudentRecord student[]={
       {10,85.2,'A',first_student},{11,66,'C',second_student}       
    };

   std::cout << student[1].allgrade.quiz << std::endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: how do you know that OP does not want `allgrade` to be an array with two elements? Also OP has `student` as global, you dont, which is prefereable, but as it is not exactly what OP asked for I'd leave a comment at least

Comment: I guess this is the desired behavior, because he wants to keep record of students' grades, and saving them on a vector of records, each one consisting on a structure (grade) that contains all possible "exams", seems the most convenient way to me. I hope I didnt missunderstood.